# Can I run the service on 443 port in docker UCP ??

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-registry, docker-ucp

I want to run a spring-boot microservice on port number 443.
I am creating this service using docker command

```
docker service create -p 443:8443 somerepo/someorg/some-service:v0.1
```

When I fire this command service goes fine, but DTR and UCP go down.
I don't have a complete idea on it but just aware of docker UCP controller run on 443.
My Question is

1. can I run my microservice as a docker service on port 443 ?
2. can I change the port number of docker UCP controller to some another port.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether port 443 is currently occupied by DTR or UCP, apparently both default to 443.

In case of UCP, according to the [reference](https://docs.docker.com/datacenter/ucp/2.1/reference/cli/install/) and this [discussion](https://forums.docker.com/t/change-ucp-default-port/17236/2), it is possible to change the UCP port by using the `--controller-port` flag during installation. This can also be configured in the web interface under `Admin Settings -> Cluster Configuration -> Controller Port`.

As for [DTR](https://docs.docker.com/datacenter/dtr/2.2/reference/cli/install/#options), there is the flag `--replica-https-port` to also move it away from 443.

Once you have moved the competing services, there is nothing that should prevent you from having a container listen to port 443.

Comment: I will check on this. I will let u know

Comment: Is there any other way apart from docker reinstallation to achieve the objective of running the service on 443 Port ??

Comment: It seems to also be possible via the UCP web interface; I edited my answer to include that. But either way you wouldn't need to reinstall Docker, only the UCP.